# Theatre/Musical or other activities in Washington DC

Tags: washington-dc

A good friend of mine will work in Washington, DC for two months in the summer of 2012. Since she will have completed her doctoral studies by then me and some firends (we're all located in Munich, Germany) thought about a "gift certificate" as a present she could redeem while staying in Washington.

We thought about a voucher for a musical show, a fancy restaurant or so. Is there antyhing a Washington resident could recommend? It should be bookable by us in advance and be in the price range of 100-200 USD.

Comment: The way this question currently stands it is very far from the types of questions Stack Exchange wants. The site is for questions specifically with "one correct answer" and not for questions that would attract a list of answers or subjective answers such as broad recommendations. Is there any way you can make the question less broad to avoid getting downvotes or closed?

Comment: Hi Mrcabana.  Great to see new people on here.  However, if you have a look at our [faq] you'll see we really try to keep questions to the type that can be objectively answered.  What type of show do you like? There are literally thousands of restaurants in Washington, it's far too broad a question.  If you'd like to raise it again with a more specific scope, or perhaps edit this one, I'm sure there'll be some people keen to answer as best as they can! :)

Answer (score 5):

There is no dearth of fine dining options or theatrical performances in Washington, DC. In fact, the [Kennedy Center](http://www.kennedy-center.org/), during the summer, has free concerts, almost every evening. These are often by Philharmonic Orchestras, which are truly wonderful. The ambiance and the location is second to none. They do have great visiting (paid) performances as well, from diverse performers, depending on your friend's interests.

For a quintessential DC dining experience, I would recommend the [Old Ebbitt Grill](http://www.ebbitt.com/main/home.cfm?Section=Main&Category=About_the_Ebbitt). She will be dining a mere block from the White House, in the midst of senators. It is reasonably priced as well.